# Angular 1 directive slow to update view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I have a screen which has a loading spinner at start up. On this screen, I have a controller that passes a property to a directive. The directive has an ng-show based upon this property.

Once I have set the above property to true, I want the directive to show the content and I want the controller to hide the loading spinner.

What is happening is, the spinner is being hidden before the directive renders the ng-show. This causes a flicker. I would expect the directive to completely loaded by the time I have hidden the spinner.

This is in the controller:

```
showSpinner();
$scope.showContent = true;
hideSpinner();
```

This is the directive initializer:

```
<div content-directive show-content="showContent "></div>
```

This is me passing in the property into my directive:

```
return {
        scope:
        {
            showContent : "="
        }
    };
```

this is my directive markup:

```
<div ng-show="showContent ">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color:dodgerblue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe toss the `hideSpinner()` inside a `$timeout()`?

Comment: @Lex This can't be right, surely?

Comment: Cheers @Lex although this wasn't the issue, It was able to help me diagnose the problem with my colleague's code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using ng-cloak on your div of content you want to be shown. From the docs:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

```
<div ng-cloak ng-show="showContent ">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color:dodgerblue"></div>
</div>
```

Then, also from the docs:

> When this css rule is loaded by the browser, all html elements
>   (including their children) that are tagged with the ngCloak directive
>   are hidden. When AngularJS encounters this directive during the
>   compilation of the template it deletes the ngCloak element attribute,
>   making the compiled element visible.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak